# How to find out which package/procedure is updating a table?

Tags: plsql

I would like to find out if it is possible to find out which package or procedure in a package is updating a table?

Due to a certain project being handed over (the person who handed over the project has since left) without proper documentation, data that we know we have updated always go back to some strange source point.

We are guessing that this could be a database job or scheduler that is running the update command without our knowledge. I am hoping that there is a way to find out where the source code is calling from that is updating the table and inserting the source as a trigger on that table that we are monitoring.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> UPDATE:  I poked around and found out
>   how to trace a statement back to its
>   owning PL/SQL object.

In combination with what Tony mentioned, you can create a logging table and a trigger that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE statement_tracker
( SID NUMBER
, serial# NUMBER
, date_run DATE
, program VARCHAR2(48) null
, module VARCHAR2(48) null
, machine VARCHAR2(64) null
, osuser VARCHAR2(30) null
, sql_text CLOB null
, program_id number
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER smb_t_t
   AFTER UPDATE
   ON smb_test
BEGIN
   INSERT 
     INTO statement_tracker
   SELECT ss.SID
        , ss.serial#
        , sysdate
        , ss.program
        , ss.module
        , ss.machine
        , ss.osuser
        , sq.sql_fulltext
        , sq.program_id
     FROM v$session ss
        , v$sql sq
    WHERE ss.sql_address = sq.address
      AND ss.SID = USERENV('sid');
END;
/
```

In order for the trigger above to compile, you'll need to grant the owner of the trigger these permissions, when logged in as the SYS user:

```
grant select on V_$SESSION to <user>;
grant select on V_$SQL to <user>;
```

You will likely want to protect the insert statement in the trigger with some condition that only makes it log when the the change you're interested in is occurring - on my test server this statement runs rather slowly (1 second), so I wouldn't want to be logging all these updates.  Of course, in that case, you'd need to change the trigger to be a row-level one so that you could inspect the :new or :old values.  If you are really concerned about the overhead of the select, you can change it to not join against v$sql, and instead just save the SQL_ADDRESS column, then schedule a job with DBMS_JOB to go off and update the sql_text column with a second update statement, thereby offloading the update into another session and not blocking your original update.

Unfortunately, this will only tell you half the story.  The statement you're going to see logged is going to be the most proximal statement - in this case, an update - even if the original statement executed by the process that initiated it is a stored procedure.  This is where the program_id column comes in.  If the update statement is part of a procedure or trigger, program_id will point to the object_id of the code in question - you can resolve it thusly:

```
SELECT * FROM all_objects where object_id = <program_id>;
```

In the case when the update statement was executed directly from the client, I don't know what program_id represents, but you wouldn't need it - you'd have the name of the executable in the "program" column of statement_tracker.  If the update was executed from an anonymous PL/SQL block, I'm not how to track it back - you'll need to experiment further.

It may be, though, that the osuser/machine/program/module information may be enough to get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a scheduled database job then you can find out what scheduled database jobs exist and look into what they do.  Other things you can do are:

- look at the dependencies views e.g. ALL_DEPENDENCIES to see what packages/triggers etc. use that table.  Depending on the size of your system that may return a lot of objects to trawl through.
- Search all the database source code for references to the table like this:

  select distinct type, name
  from   all_source
  where lower(text) like lower('%mytable%');

Again that may return a lot of objects, and of course there will be some "false positives" where the search string appears but isn't actually a reference to that table.  You could even try something more specific like:

```
select distinct type, name
from   all_source
where lower(text) like lower('%insert into mytable%');
```

but of course that would miss cases where the command was formatted differently.

Additionally, could there be SQL scripts being run through "cron" jobs on the server?

Comment: Hi Tony,

Thanks for the update. I have checked all users in cron and doubt if a scheduler is causing the update..

I'll try running the sql statement suggested... Thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

Just write an "after update"  trigger and,  in this trigger,  log the results of "DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK"  in a dedicated table.

The purpose of this function is exactly to give you the complete  call stack of al the stored procedures and triggers that have been fired to reach your code. 
 I am writing from the mobile app,  so i can't give you more detailed examples,  but if you google for it you'll find many of them.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty option if you're working locally, and are only interested in the first thing that's altering the data, is to throw an error in the trigger instead of logging. That way, you get the usual stack trace and it's a lot less typing and you don't need to create a new table:

```
AFTER UPDATE ON table_of_interest
BEGIN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'something changed it');
END;
/
```